# Electric Force is to Magnetic Force as Gravitational Force is to ...?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

One can no nothing about the magnetic force and yet arrive at it by taking the relativistic effects of a current and a moving charge system into account. I ask whether there exists such an inherent force in case of gravity.

Comment: Hi Swapnanil - it would help improve the question a lot if you explained in more detail what you're asking for here.

Comment: Whether there exists any such force, in whatever form

Comment: Well, I meant edit the question to clarify this. It'll read better if you explain in sentences.

Comment: You are asking about gravito-magnetic forces, which are included in General Relativity. This has been asked many times in different guises, although I wouldn't remember the exact duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11096/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Einstein's theory of gravity is already relativistic so I *think* that what you're asking is this:  beginning with Newtonian gravity and making an analogy with Coulomb's law (where mass is analogous to electric charge etc.), and taking into account special relativity effects of a (mass) current etc., does the analog of magnetic force pop out?

The answer is:  yes.  However and unfortunately, the gravitational waves that also pop out, analogous to electromagnetic waves, transport negative energy.

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of such forces that commonly known as gravitomagnetic forces:

http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2004/19apr_gravitomagnetism/

http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap110510.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitomagnetic_field

(I doubt though why the Wikipedia currently uses non-common name though).